# I want to call relation-changed hook from config-changed hook

Tags: juju

I want to call the relation-changed hook whenever there is a config-change and config-change hook is called. Can i directly call relation-changed from config-change hook. My config-change hook is written in bash.

```
config-change:
#!/bin/bash
...
relation-changed
```

Is it the right way to call it. Appreciate your response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* but I would recommend putting any shared code in a shared utils script and then call that from both your relation-changed hook and your config-change hook.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relation is called `foo`, you should always be able to call:

```
$CHARM_DIR/hooks/foo-relation-changed
```

...but hatch's suggestion that you write library code, and use that directly, is a good one.